# Json.net Converter not getting called

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a json string that comes back as:

{ "expires_in": 300 }

I defined a class:

```
class Test
{
   public DateTime ExpirationDate {get;set;}
}
```

Now I want to deserialize into that object, but want to convert the 300 to mean DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(300) so I did:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>("{ \"expires_in\": 300 }");
```

So I tried:

```
class Test
{
   [JsonProperty("expires_in", ItemConverterType=typeof(TestConverter))]
   public DateTime ExpirationDate {get;set;}
}
```

But it never seems to get into the converter. Am I missing something?

Converter is just stubbed out:

```
class TestConvert : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share your `TestConverter`?

Comment: @Minijack Added, but its just stubbed out right now. None of those are getting hit.

Comment: if `CanConvert` does not return true then it will not try and convert the value

Comment: @Minijack it doesn't even get into any of those methods...

Comment: try `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>("{ \"expires_in\": 300 }", new TestConvert());`

Comment: @Minijack when I do that, it gets into it for the Test object. Isn't it supposed to do it for each property that has the converter on it?

Comment: use `Converter` rather then `ItemConverter` as `ItemConverter` is for collections, see [docs](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty.htm)

Comment: @Minijack Yeah, I had to change to   [JsonProperty("expires_in")]
  [JsonConverter(typeof(TestConverter))]
  public DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }
to get it to work. Can't do it with a single attribute I guess. Thanks!

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of [Why serializing Version with JsonPropertyAttribute doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38319910/3744182) and/or [Proper way of using Newtonsoft Json ItemConverterType](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24640305/3744182).